# WPF avoiding method calls in Property Setter?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Model property bound to the text of a `RichTextBox`. The text is changed on `SelectedItem` from a `ListBox` & all is working well.

The bound text is coming in as `Html` and I need to convert it to `Rtf` to be presented in the `RTB`. I have the converter class all coded up for this. This feels dirty but I'm currently calling the convert methods from the property setter:

```
   private viewArticle _SelectedArticle;
    public viewArticle SelectedArticle
    {
        get { return _SelectedArticle; }
        set
        {
            _SelectedArticle = value;

            _SelectedArticle.ArticleBody = HtmlToXamlConverter.ConvertHtmlToXaml(_SelectedArticle.ArticleBody.ToString(), true);
            _SelectedArticle.ArticleBody = ConvertXamlToRtf(_SelectedArticle.ArticleBody.ToString());

            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedArticle");
        }
    }
```

My problem occurs when I have some filters in the view which changes my `ListBox` and nulls my `SelectedArticle` property. Obviously when the methods are invoked I get a 'null exception'. Is there a better way of handling this behaviour, can I  take the method calls out of the property setter?

Comment: can't you just add `RtfArticleBody` property (set in constructor) to your `viewArticle` class?

Comment: I would use a converter in the binding and not in the setter. So the setter sets the private variable and notifies of the property change. You have bindings bound to SelectedArticle with a converter. That converter would check for null as well as handle the convert when needed.

Comment: Only a comment.  if (_SelectedArticle == null) return;  if (_SelectedArticle == value) return;

Comment: @Paul, I could be wrong, but judging by the method name called in the `setter`, that `HtmlToXamlConverter` class is *not* an `IValueConverter` implementation.

Comment: @Hardgraf, apart from the fact that you're not checking for `null` in your `setter`, I don't see anything wrong with your code... of course, you *could* declare an `HtmlToRtfConverter` to save yourself one conversion, but in principle, there's absolutely nothing wrong with calling a method from a property.

Comment: Ok thanks @Sheridan, wasn't sure if calling methods from property setters was bad practice or not. I've tried to test for null with (if _SelectedArticle != null) { invoke method calls } but it fails on the If condition as it's testing a null value...

Comment: *I've tried to test for null with (if _SelectedArticle != null) { invoke method calls } but it fails on the If condition as it's testing a null value*... I don't understand... what do you mean *it fails on the If condition as it's testing a null value*. If the `_SelectedArticle` property was `null`, then your `if` statement would be the same as `if (null != null) { ... }`... there would be no error, but program execution would never enter the braces... which is what you want. You just need to make sure that everything in the property setter is within the `if` statement braces.

Comment: @Sheridan, Got it! In the setter I set the value then test the null condition: set{ _SelectedArticle = value; if(_selectedArticle != null) { invoke methods(); OnPropChanged("SelectedArticle"); } Somtimes I wonder whether I'm cut out for this job...

Comment: *Sometimes I wonder whether I'm cut out for this job*... we all learn from our mistakes, so the more mistakes we make, the more we learn. ;)

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? Link: [IValueConverter Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @MC yeah that's the interface used to create a custom converter class. I solved my issue by simply testing for null in the property setter.